# Opaque body background going over fixed header

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header. When the background of my body is a solid color everything works fine - the body text goes under the header. If I make the body background opaque then the body goes over the header instead of under it. The nav bar and logo etc. goes in the "headContent" div.

```
<body>
    <div id="headContent">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Content stuff.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The header code is in a separate file so I have php linking to it. So, the css for the div containing content that goes under the header:

```
#content{
    padding-top: 140px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

But as soon as I add opacity the content goes over the header:

```
#content{
    padding-top: 140px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Seems simple. I've tried using the z-index. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a complete code example. Also, `z-index` only works with positioned (i.e. non-static) elements.

Comment: [`opacity` with a value less than `1` creates a new stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) – that’s the explanation for your problem. And if the header is already fixed, then simply adding a `z-index` to it should fix the problem.

Comment: This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you could try to add the following instead of opacity in your css you could try to do it like this

```
#content{
padding-top: 140px;
background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```